# How do you return a thank you page after a form submission in meteor

Tags: meteor

I want to display a thank you page after submitting a form in meteor.  How do I call this page?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a precise answer without more details about the form or the target action, but this may give you an idea:

```js
Template.myTemplate.events({
  submit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Router.go('thank-you');
  }
});
```

In this example, after submitting the form we prevent the default action (a POST which will reload the page), and instead we route to the `thank-you` page. Alternatively, you could do something like show a modal, alert, etc.